# Erro no idioma do mês Django

Tags: python, django

Bom dia galera,

Seguinte, estou com um problema bem incomodo. Quando eu tento utilizar a data que foi armazenada no banco de dados, ela vem com o mês em inglês.

settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-br'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Sao_Paulo'

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

E dai no template aparece assim:

```
A última atualização foi no dia 5 de February de 2017 às 09:19
```

A minha versão do Django é a 1.10.4

Comment: Esá utilizando MySQL?

Comment: Não lembro se é case sensitive, mas acho que o [correto](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm) seja `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'pt-BR'`.

Comment: Continuou igual

Answer (score 4):

Se estiver utilizando o banco de dados MySQL, o problema deve estar na variável `lc_time_names`. Para verificar, utilize a seguinte instrução:

```
SELECT @@lc_time_names;
```

O retorno deve ser algo parecido com isso:

```
+-----------------+
| @@lc_time_names |
+-----------------+
| en_US           |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

`en_US` é o valor padrão no MySQL e provavelmente este é o seu problema. Para alterá-lo para `pt_BR`, execute a instrução:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
```

Desta forma, ao verificar novamente o valor da variável, o retorno será:

```
+-----------------+
| @@lc_time_names |
+-----------------+
| pt_BR           |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

E assim, se fizer o teste com a data:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d de %M de %Y');
```

Seu retorno será:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%d de %M de %Y') |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| 05 de fevereiro de 2017                         |
+-------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Perceba a data em português. Porém, desta maneira, ao fechar a sessão com o MySQL, a variável retornará ao seu valor padrão, necessitando que você faça a atualização para `pt_BR` toda vez que conectar-se ao banco. Para contornar este problema, você pode definir a variável no escopo global, com a instrução:

```
SET GLOBAL lc_time_names=pt_BR;
```

Mas não sei dizer se definir ela globalmente traz algum risco à sua aplicação.

Comment: Não, estou usando o PostgreSQL. Porém ele está setado para o Brasil.

Comment: Executando o comando no PSQL:

SELECT to_char(DATE'2017-02-06','TMDay - d "de" TMMonth "de" YYYY');
                
to_char
----------------------------------------
 Segunda-Feira - 2 de Fevereiro de 2017
(1 registro)